# Show that the sequence $x_N$ converges weakly and compute the weak limit

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $\{ e_k \}_{k = 1}^\infty $ be an orthonormal basis for $H$. I am trying to prove that the sequence

$$x_N = \frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_{k = 1}^N e_k $$
converges weakly and to find its weak limit.

*What I know so far:*

Proving weak convergence of $u_N$ to $u$ means
proving that $\ell (u_N) \to \ell(u)$ for all functionals $\ell$ defined as $\ell :H \to \mathbb R$. In a Hilbert space, however, linear functionals take the form $\ell(u_N) = \langle u,u_N \rangle $ for some unique $u$ that changes only when $\ell$ changes.

**Could someone give me any clues in proving the above, i.e., that the weak limit exist and how to find it.**

Comment: Really an [Orthonormal basis][1] or a [Schauder Basis][2] ?


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis
  [2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis

Comment: I posted an answer and then deleted it. I may edit it further and then undelete it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Take your time. Thanks.

Comment: @Maksim orthonormal.

Comment: might also help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508006/compute-norm-and-weak-limit-in-hilbert-space-of-un-frac1-sqrtn-sum?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $\left\langle x_N, e_j \right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \to 0$, as $N \to \infty$. Thus, by linearity, for any $y = a_1 e_1 + \ldots + a_r e_r$, we have $\left\langle x_N, e_j \right\rangle \to 0$. Let $y \in H$, with $y = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e_n$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Get $R$ so large that $\| y - \sum_{k=1}^R  a_n e_n\|_H < \epsilon$. Then,

$$|\left\langle x_N, y \right\rangle| \leq \left| \left\langle x_N, \sum_{k=1}^R  a_n e_n \right\rangle  \right| + \left| \left\langle x_N, \sum_{k=R+1}^\infty  a_n e_n \right\rangle \right| \leq \underbrace{\left| \left\langle x_N, \sum_{k=1}^R  a_n e_n \right\rangle  \right|}_{\to 0 } + \epsilon$$

Where the last inequality is Cauchy-Schwartz with $\|x_N\| = 1$. We may send $N \to \infty$ and conclude to $x_N$ converges to zero weakly.

Comment: Standard typographical usage is $\|x\|$ rather than $||x||,$ and it that difference is not clear enough, contrast $||x|| ||y||,$ coded as `||x|| ||y||`, with $\|x\|\|y\|,$ coded as `\|x\|\|y\|`. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks! I was wondering why my norms looked so weird...

Comment: @JoseAvilez If I got you right, you have proved that $\ell \left( {{x_N}} \right) \to 0$. But if thats the case how do you conclude that $x=0$ is the weak limit. All I can see is that $\ell \left( {{x_N}} \right) \to \ell \left( x \right) = 0$

Comment: @Karim if $\ell (x) = 0$ for all $\ell \in H^*$ then $x = 0$.

Comment: why did you start the inequality by $\left\langle {{x_N},{e_j}} \right\rangle $. Shouldn't you start directly by second part as you are trying to show that $\ell \left( {{x_N}} \right) = \left\langle {{x_N},y} \right\rangle  \to 0$ ?

Comment: @Sam That was a typo. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

$\{x_n\}$ converges weakly to 0.

It suffices to show that
$$
\langle x_n,y\rangle\to 0,
$$
for all $y\in H$.

Let $y\in H$, then $y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ne_n$, where
$a_n=\langle y,e_n\rangle$, and $\|y\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$.
Hence
$$
\langle x_n,y\rangle=\left\langle \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ne_k,\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ne_n\right\rangle=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k.
$$
Clearly, since the sequence $\{a^n\}$ is summable, then $a^2\to 0$, and hence $a_n\to 0$ as well. So does the sequence
$$
b_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k.
$$
See for example [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

Comment: Doesn't $x_n$ have division by $\sqrt{n},$ not $n$?

Comment: @cmk I have the same remark. Hence, $n$ will cancel out, and we can not take the limit.

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis how could you conclude that $a_n \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @Sam See the improved version of my answer.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I read it already. It is not apparent why $a_n$ would go to zero. A counter example, for instance, is that $y$ could be the vector of all ones.

Comment: @Sam $y$ can not be such a vector, since if $y=\sum a_ne_n$, then $\|y\|^2=\sum a^2_n$ and hence $a_n^2\to 0$.

Comment: I see. The sequence must converge and hence it must vanish at $\infty$

Comment: Why not estimating $\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k| \le (\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^2)^{1/2}\le \|y\|^2$? DO I miss something?